# How to sketch the graph of this function without calculator?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$f(x)=\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\cos2x$$

How to draw the graph of it？

If I apply the double angle identity to the function, it turns into $f(x)=\cos x+\frac{2\cos^2x-1}{2}$

It is still hard to sketch. Then how to do it?

Comment: Please give us some context.  None of us want to spend 20 minutes typing out a calculus-based answer only to find out that you haven't taken calculus yet.  And we sure don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: I have learned differentiation. Do I need to take it first derivative to look at its stationary point, and then look at its inflection point?

Comment: Yes.  The stationary points are easy.  The inflection points are a bit ugly.   But just he stationary points will give you a good picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As B Goddard stated, you'll discover that the stationary (critical) points of $f'(x) = -(\sin x + \sin 2x).$  You might have to expand $\sin 2x$ to get an equation that you can set equal to zero.

For the inflection points, $f''(x) = -(\cos x + 2 \cos 2x)$, and again, you'll need to expand $\cos 2x$ to get an equation to set equal to zero; if you do so, you will have a quadratic in $x$ but the roots are very messy.